# Post-install failure in boot on one laptop; other PCs install AOK

Tags: boot, software-installation, hardware

Laptop Model:
Dell Inspiron 15 5000 Series

My laptop boots to a black screen every time after I install it; other desktops install AOK from the same LiveUSB of Ubuntu 18.04.3. Error message as follows:

```
[  0.162116  ] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 6: ee20000000
[  0.162119  ] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR fef1ce80 MISC 43880014086
[  0.162123  ] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:806e9 TIME 1568714001 SOCKET 0
[  0.162126  ] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 7: ee20000000
[  0.162128  ] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR fef1ce40 MISC 7880014086
[  0.162131  ] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:806e9 TIME 1568714001 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode b4
[  8.034500  ] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed4000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
[  8.034593  ] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire commend/response buffer. [mem 0xfed4000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
[  8.082407  ] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
```

Comment: Kindly click the link ( enter image description here)  to see picture of the error message

Comment: @K7AAY Yes its working fine on every PC that i installed but when i installed to my laptop the error message appear  the version Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: So, after you install, Ubuntu from that LiveUSB fails on one laptop only, but installs and runs OK on other PCs. What is the make and model of that laptop? Please get the model# from the sticker which also has the serial number, other models are not helpful. Also, how much RAM is in that laptop, ans is it in one or two memory modules? Please put answer in the question with [edit]; please do not use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].